# iOS - Saving a wallpaper in SpringBoard directory

Tags: ios, jailbreak, wallpaper, springboard

I jailbroke my iPod and I am making an app to change the wallpaper. I've already copied my wallpaper (image.png) to the SpringBoard folder.
But the wallpaper in iOS are saved in the cpbitmap format and I don't know how I can generate this kind of file.

Anybody know how to create a cpbitmap file in iOS with the SDK?

Regards

PS: My iPod has iOS 5.1

Comment: I'd also like to know this. Have you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

The SpringBoardServices (private) framework has C functions to set and get the current wallpaper.
Disassembling the frameworks binary would most likely answer your question